# Bitbucket API for updating the build status for a pull request

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

I see the docs for updating the build status for a commit:
https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/commit/%7Bnode%7D/statuses/build

For a pull request, isn't there a unique commit associated with it? Is there no API for updating a PR's build status? Or do we just need to discover which commit is associated with the PR, and then just update the build status for that commit?

For example this view:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

You can see on the right that the commit to the temp branch has a passing build status - but the way it works is it should merge *temp into master* into some new commit/branch and I need to be able to test that.

The view that I want to update is at url:

```
https://bitbucket.org/<user>/<repo>/pull-requests/1/<commit-message>/diff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to this this url and type "build" and you will find the relevant routes:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Bitbucket does not have Builds on PRs (Check [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/check-build-status-in-a-pull-request-945541505.html)), What you need is one Successful Build on the **LAST** Commit:

[image]

Then, you can use the API to push the build to that one after you have done what you need to test it.

This guide is really simple to use:
https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/updating-build-status-for-commits/

The only recommendation I have on the guide is that it didn't work for me with curl, then, what I did was to do it with Postman and then exported the command to curl and that's it...

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/{your space}/{Your Repo}/commit/{The long hash of your commit}/statuses/build?Content-Type=application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic {your token}=' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "state": "SUCCESSFUL",
    "key": "MANUAL-BUILD",
    "name": "Manual Build",
    "url": "http://this.really.doesnt.matter/",
    "description": "Successful Build done manually"
}'
```